# What * does in python (besides being just multiplication sign)

Tags: python, format

I found such syntax:

```
dota_teams = ["Liquid", "Virtus.pro", "PSG.LGD", "Team Secret"]
data = [[1, 2, 1, 'x'],
['x', 1, 1, 'x'],
[1, 'x', 0, 1],
[2, 0, 2, 1]]
format_row = "{:>12}" * (len(dota_teams) + 1)
print(format_row.format("", *dota_teams))
for team, row in zip(dota_teams, data):
    print(format_row.format(team, *row))
```

I don't understand fully what "*" does here. (In .format() argument before "dota_teams" or "row") .

What is it responsible for in this syntax?

Comment: @MikeScotty That doesn't look like it fits this question at all.  This question has the code `"{:>12}" * (len(dota_teams) + 1)` wheras your suggested duplicate has code like `*args`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller true, when you look only at the question, but please scroll to the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36926/4349415) | EDIT: seems I misunderstood you, because you may have OP's question wrong. OP is asking about ``*`` before ``dota_teams`` and ``row``, not the string multiplication

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the question and answer supply information regarding both keyword arguments (`**`) and args (`*`).

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You're looking at the one asterisk they're **not** asking about.

Comment: To be fair, the line I picked out also has `dota_teams` after the asterisk (but not directly after.)  Darn not-minimal example code.